# How to add an array to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array items with some arrays. Now I want to add an array item_optional to the top of array items.

This is what I've tried, but I think this is not correct:

```
$item_optional = array(
    'harry' => array('name'=>'test1', 'code'=>1697, 'hmp'=>'x1')
);

$items = array(
    'denise'  => array('name'=>'test2', 'code'=>2697, 'hmp'=>'x2'),
    'mike'    => array('name'=>'test3', 'code'=>3697, 'hmp'=>'x3'),
    'richard' => array('name'=>'test4', 'code'=>4697, 'hmp'=>'x4')
);

array_unshift($items, $item_optional);
```

The output should be:

```
$items = array(
    'harry'   => array('name'=>'test1', 'code'=>1697, 'hmp'=>'x1'),
    'denise'  => array('name'=>'test2', 'code'=>2697, 'hmp'=>'x2'),
    'mike'    => array('name'=>'test3', 'code'=>3697, 'hmp'=>'x3'),
    'richard' => array('name'=>'test4', 'code'=>4697, 'hmp'=>'x4')
);
```

Comment: array_merge() array_merge — Merge one or more arrays http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php even http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php could work here. You've many choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
$item_optional = array(
    'harry' => array('name'=>'test1', 'code'=>1697, 'hmp'=>'x1')
);

$items = array(
    'denise'  => array('name'=>'test2', 'code'=>2697, 'hmp'=>'x2'),
    'mike'    => array('name'=>'test3', 'code'=>3697, 'hmp'=>'x3'),
    'richard' => array('name'=>'test4', 'code'=>4697, 'hmp'=>'x4')
);
```

The code:

```
$items = $item_optional + $items;
```

Result:

```
array (size=4)
  'harry' => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'test1' (length=5)
      'code' => int 1697
      'hmp' => string 'x1' (length=2)
  'denise' => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'test2' (length=5)
      'code' => int 2697
      'hmp' => string 'x2' (length=2)
  'mike' => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'test3' (length=5)
      'code' => int 3697
      'hmp' => string 'x3' (length=2)
  'richard' => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'test4' (length=5)
      'code' => int 4697
      'hmp' => string 'x4' (length=2)
```

Comment: `$item_optional + $items` this isn't JS ;-) `+` works?

Comment: Hm.. Sorry, I didn't get it. I think it works (at least for this case).

Comment: I guess there's something I don't know about arrays lol I thought "+" was the concatenate in JS, as opposed to a dot `.` in PHP. I learned something today ;-) *weirdly*.

Comment: Great, usually it's you that teach someone something. Here is a bit of knowledge to you as a compensation.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis Everyone learns something from each other, no matter how much rep one has ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$items = array_merge( $item_optional, $items );
```

or you can use the [+ operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```
$items = $item_optional + $items;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use array_merge().

This will put the array at the end of the other array.  Then your first argument will be your array on top and the second argument will be the array on end.

```
$items = array_merge( $item_optional, $items );
```

More information: [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)